# Run Stata do file from Python

Tags: python, stata

I have a `Python` script that cleans up and performs basic statistical calculations on a large panel dataset (`2,000,000+ observations`).

I find that some of these tasks are better suited to `Stata`, and wrote a do file with the necessary commands. Thus, I want to run a .do file within my Python code. How would I go about calling a `.do` file from `Python`?

Comment: How do you normally run such files? Do you use a command line interface?  If so, what do you enter?

Comment: I usually run do files by opening stata, and typing do <filename>.do into the command line. However, I have many do files to process, and it would be easier if I could consolidate and run them from the Python file.

Comment: What platform are you running on?

Comment: Have a look at Andrew's comments under my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18532440/in-sublime-text-3-can-i-send-a-selection-of-a-do-file-to-stata - perhaps of some help.

Comment: @ wnnmaw I use Windows 7 at work and Mac OS X 10.8 at home. @radek Thanks! That was a very helpful question to look at.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think @user229552 points in the correct direction. Python's `subprocess` module can be used. Below an example that works for me with Linux OS.

Suppose you have a Python file called `pydo.py` with the following:

```
import subprocess

## Do some processing in Python

## Set do-file information
dofile = "/home/roberto/Desktop/pyexample3.do"
cmd = ["stata", "do", dofile, "mpg", "weight", "foreign"]

## Run do-file
subprocess.call(cmd)
```

and a Stata do-file named `pyexample3.do`, with the following:

```
clear all
set more off

local y `1'
local x1 `2'
local x2 `3'

display `"first parameter: `y'"'
display `"second parameter: `x1'"'
display `"third parameter: `x2'"'

sysuse auto
regress `y' `x1' `x2'

exit, STATA clear
```

Then executing `pydo.py` in a Terminal window works as expected.

You could also define a Python function and use that:

```
## Define a Python function to launch a do-file 
def dostata(dofile, *params):
    ## Launch a do-file, given the fullpath to the do-file
    ## and a list of parameters.
    import subprocess    
    cmd = ["stata", "do", dofile]
    for param in params:
        cmd.append(param)
    return subprocess.call(cmd) 

## Do some processing in Python

## Run a do-file
dostata("/home/roberto/Desktop/pyexample3.do", "mpg", "weight", "foreign")
```

The complete call from a Terminal, with results:

```
roberto@roberto-mint ~/Desktop
$ python pydo.py

  ___  ____  ____  ____  ____ (R)
 /__    /   ____/   /   ____/
___/   /   /___/   /   /___/   12.1   Copyright 1985-2011 StataCorp LP
  Statistics/Data Analysis            StataCorp
                                      4905 Lakeway Drive
                                      College Station, Texas 77845 USA
                                      800-STATA-PC        http://www.stata.com
                                      979-696-4600        stata@stata.com
                                      979-696-4601 (fax)


Notes:
      1.  Command line editing enabled

. do /home/roberto/Desktop/pyexample3.do mpg weight foreign 

. clear all

. set more off

. 
. local y `1'

. local x1 `2'

. local x2 `3'

. 
. display `"first parameter: `y'"'
first parameter: mpg

. display `"second parameter: `x1'"'
second parameter: weight

. display `"third parameter: `x2'"'
third parameter: foreign

. 
. sysuse auto
(1978 Automobile Data)

. regress `y' `x1' `x2'

      Source |       SS       df       MS              Number of obs =      74
-------------+------------------------------           F(  2,    71) =   69.75
       Model |   1619.2877     2  809.643849           Prob > F      =  0.0000
    Residual |  824.171761    71   11.608053           R-squared     =  0.6627
-------------+------------------------------           Adj R-squared =  0.6532
       Total |  2443.45946    73  33.4720474           Root MSE      =  3.4071

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
         mpg |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
      weight |  -.0065879   .0006371   -10.34   0.000    -.0078583   -.0053175
     foreign |  -1.650029   1.075994    -1.53   0.130      -3.7955    .4954422
       _cons |    41.6797   2.165547    19.25   0.000     37.36172    45.99768
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. 
. exit, STATA clear
```

**Sources:**

http://www.reddmetrics.com/2011/07/15/calling-stata-from-python.html

http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html

http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/unix/batch-mode/

A different route for using Python and Stata together can be found at

http://ideas.repec.org/c/boc/bocode/s457688.html

http://www.stata.com/statalist/archive/2013-08/msg01304.html

Comment: Thanks, this was very helpful. However, I'm running into another error when I implement this solution in Windows. I get the following message:  `WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified`

Comment: Ah, I figured out what I'm doing wrong - first, because I'm running from Windows XP, I should be passing the `shell = 'true'` argument in the `subprocess.call()` method. Second, my Python code was not in the same working directory as is my copy of Stata. Once I fixed these two issues, everything ran smoothly. Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 5):

This answer extends @Roberto Ferrer's answer, solving a few issues I ran into.

**Stata in system path**

For `stata` to run code, it must be correctly set up in the system path (on Windows at least). At least for me, this was not automatically set up on installing Stata, and i found the simplest correction was to put in the full path (which for me was `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Stata12\Stata-64`) i.e.:

```
cmd = ["C:\Program Files (x86)\Stata12\Stata-64","do", dofile]`
```

**How to quietly run the code in the background**

It is possible to get the code to run quietly in the background (i.e. not opening up Stata each time), by adding the command `/e`  i.e.

`cmd = ["C:\Program Files (x86)\Stata12\Stata-64,"/e","do", dofile]`

**Log file storage location**

Finally, if you are running quietly in the background, Stata will will want to save log files. It will do this in `cmd`'s working directory. This must vary depending on where the code is being run from, but for me, since i was executing Python from Notepad++, it wanted to save the log files in  `C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++` , which Stata did not have write-access to. This can be changed by specifying the working directory when the sub-process is called.

These modifications to `Roberto Ferrer`'s code lead to:

```
def dostata(dofile, *params):
    cmd = ["C:\Program Files (x86)\Stata12\Stata-64","/e","do", dofile]         
    for param in params:
        cmd.append(param)
    return (subprocess.call(cmd, cwd=r'C:\location_to_save_log_files'))
```

Comment: Spent so long trying to figure out that `"stata"` would not work, and instead I needed to define the full path to the Stata executable as you did.

Answer (score 1):

If you're running this in a command-line setting, you should be able to call Stata from the command line from python (I don't know how to invoke a shell command from within Python, but it shouldn't be too hard, see here: [Calling an external command in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python)). To run Stata from the command line (aka batch mode), see here: http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/unix/batch-mode/