# How to run a Stata do-file from Python in MacOS

Tags: python, stata

I am new to Python, and am trying to execute a Stata do-file from Python, **using MacOS**.

Following advice in this question: [Run Stata do file from Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21263668/run-stata-do-file-from-python)

I tried the following code:

```
dofile = folder_path + "stata_dofile.do"
cmd = ["C:/Program Files (x86)/Stata14/StataSE-64", "do", dofile, variable1, variable2]
subprocess.call(cmd)
```

where "dofile" is the Stata do file I want to execute, and "variable1" and "variable2" are some string variables I want to feed to Stata.

This code works fine on Windows. But when I try to adapt it to the Mac as follows:

```
dofile = folder_path + "stata_dofile.do"
cmd = ["/Applications/Stata/StataMP.app", "do", dofile, variable1, variable2]
subprocess.call(cmd)
```

I get an error message "permission denied."

Following some other advice on this forum, I did manage to open the Stata app from Python on my Mac, using the following code:

```
cmd = ["/usr/bin/open", "/Applications/Stata/StataMP.app"]
subprocess.call(cmd)
```

But this only opens Stata, and I don't know how to modify the code to make it execute the do-file above.

Basically I have no idea what I'm doing. Would really appreciate any tips!

Answer (score 0):

I figure this out!

Suppose we have a `test.do` file in desktop like this:

```
sysuse auto, clear

fsum price mpg, s(mean median sd max min) f(%12.3f)
```

We should not use StataSE.app, instead, we should open its package contents:

```
import subprocess

cmd = ["/Applications/Stata/StataSE.app/Contents/MacOS/StataSE", "do", "/Users/apple/Desktop/test.do"]

subprocess.call(cmd)
```

I hope this would be helpful